# How is $\Bbb Z_0 = \{0, \pm m, \pm2m, \pm3m, \ldots\}$ denoted in set builder notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\Bbb Z_0$ has integers as its elements, and its elements are listed as follows:
$\Bbb Z_0 = \{0, \pm m, \pm2m, \pm3m, \ldots\}$

Then how is $\Bbb Z_0$ denoted in set builder notation?
Is there a correct representation for the set $\Bbb Z_0$ between the following two?

$\Bbb Z_0=$ {$x \in \Bbb Z\,|\, x=km \text{ for some } k \in \Bbb Z\ \text{for all integer m}$}

OR

$\Bbb Z_0=$ {$x \in \Bbb Z\,|\, x=km \text{ for some } k \in \Bbb Z\ \text{for some integer m}$}

Comment: Neither of the cited versions is correct.

Comment: @JohnBentin, usually is $m\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Isn't "for all integer $m$" nor "for some integer $m$" because $m$ is fixed.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: Agreed; $m\Bbb Z$ is both standard and self-explanatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A correct version, close to the OP's style, is $$\mathbb{Z}_0=\left\{x\in \mathbb{Z}|x=km\text{ for some }k\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

$m$ needs to be a free variable, i.e. you really have $\mathbb{Z}_0(m)$.  In both examples from OP, $m$ is a bound variable, which is incorrect.

OP's first example would make $x=km$ for all $m$ at once, which is impossible.

OP's second example would allow $m$ to vary depending on $x$; hence the set would be all of $\mathbb{Z}$, which is not what was intended.

Comment: That's basically saying "$\mathbb{Z}_0$ contains all integers wich can be expressed as $km$ for some other integer $k$". While correct, that seems like a convoluted way of expressing $\mathbb{Z}_0$. Why not simply $\mathbb{Z}_0=\{\;km\;|\;k\in\mathbb{Z}\;\}$?

Comment: @fgp, as I mentioned, this is not my style; but it is (a) correct, and (b) similar to the OP's style.

Comment: Fair enough, I just wanted to mention that there's a more direct way to express this

Comment: @vadim123 Hello, what does OP mean in "OP's style"?

Comment: @buzzee Original Poster (or Original Post).

Comment: By the way I can't find "free variable" mentioned in a set theory or a discrete mathematics book. Can you recommend me what book I should read to grasp the concept of "free variable"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables

Answer (score 2):

Given $m$, we have $$\mathbb{Z}_0 = \{x\in \mathbb{Z} | x = km, k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$

Answer (score 1):

I would write it as 
$$\{z \in \mathbb{Z}\mid m \text{ divides } z \}$$ or 
$$\{z \in \mathbb{Z}\mid z \text{ is a multiple of } m \}$$
It may not fit the context, though, but then it might.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to write it $m\Bbb Z=\{mn\in\Bbb Z:n\in\Bbb Z\}$.